# Why if I try to stop a task using CancellationToken.Cancel() then the actual task get stucked on Task.Wait()?

Tags: c#, task, cancellationtokensource

I'm trying to implement a task cancellation in C#, following the examples provided my MSDN.
I have a Windows Form application with a Graph showing data coming from external devices and a start/stop button. That's the code, more or less, inside the button:

```
if (drawGraph_task == null)
{
    cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
    token = cts.Token;
    drawGraph_task = new Task(() => 
    {
        this.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(this.myChart.Series[0].Points.Clear));

        while (true)
        {
            // get x and y from device using external lib
            this.Invoke(new addPointXYDelegate(this.myChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY), new object[] { x, y });
            this.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(this.chart_pressure.Update)); // update graph

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

        }
    }, token);
    this.button_main_start.Text = "Stop";
    drawGraph_task.Start();                
}
else
{
    cts.Cancel();

    try
    {
        drawGraph_task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Dispose();
        drawGraph_task.Dispose();
        drawGraph_task = null;
        this.button_main_start.Text = "Restart";
    }
}
```

Why the code remains stucked at the drawGraph_task.Wait() call?
I tried to use the token.throwIfCancellationRequested() inside the task, but sometimed I have the same effect, sometimes the exception is not catched by my catch. What am I doing wrong?
For completeness, calculation of x and y involves:

- MathNet Interpolate library
- calls to a in-house made library for protocol specific communication that made to wait for an event (it's been always launched, so this is not the source of the problem)

Comment: does the loop reach the `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;` statement? Maybe the task stucks at the invocation of the external methods...

Comment: You're calling `drawGraph_task.Wait();`, presumably, on the UI thread. In the meantime, lots of the work your separate task is trying to do is by `Invoke` to try to get back onto the UI thread. Unless you're exceptionally lucky, it's unlikely that you'll call `Cancel` at exactly the right moment such that your worker is about to query the token.

Comment: Basically, if you're manually creating a `Task` and then having to write lots of `Invoke` based code, you're probably taken the wrong approach in splitting up your work. Here, **every** line of code in your task, except for the cancellation bits, actually needs to run on the UI thread. What was meant to be the benefit of running separately?

Comment: Wait is blocking, where are you trying to call `.Cancel` from, don't see it in the code.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars - `Cancel` is called 4 lines above `Wait`.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the `if/else` is the task initialised to one that can be cancelled? Looks like the `drawGraph_task` must be initialised to something before the if?

Comment: @tigerswithguitars - the whole `if`/`else` block is effectively a big toggle. One side initiates the task, the other side seeks to cancel it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I got the point, so the new question should be: How can I update the UI without using the Invoke?

Comment: @DanieleNardi - ideally, the in house library already supports or can be adapted to support asynchronous methods that return `Task` or `Task<T>` results. If so, then you make use of this and transform your code to use `async`/`await` and stop manually working with `Task`s yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task.Wait() is synchronous. If it happens that due to an Invoke() call you can return to this method, you get a deadlock. Use the debugger to inspect the state of your callstack when you have reached the stucked state.